# Не получаю ответ от бд

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Я человек глупый, сделал запрос **count(*)** чтобы получить общее число пользователей с **left_from_chat = 1**

```
$left_from_chat = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_confs WHERE peer_id = $peer_id AND left_from_chat = 1");
$vk->sendMessage($peer_id, $left_from_chat);
```

но он не выводит мне число $left_from_chat

Comment: а функция query возвращает число?

Comment: @Ипатьев конечно, а что же еще она должна возвращать?))))

Comment: так а мне вы можете помочь то?

Comment: Тебе поможет открытие мануала.

Comment: я уже все ,что можно открывал, дооткрывался, но не помогло

Comment: https://nolvoprosov.ru/programming/332509